# Combine the results one SQL query to the results of another SQL query to make one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm using SQL Server and I have a couple of queries that work individually, but I would like to combine them together into one table.

I've tried to take the first query and join it with the 2nd, but I'm not sure of the right syntax.

```
SELECT Store, ROUND(AVG(Unemployment),2) AS avg_unempl, 
                ROUND(AVG(CPI),2) AS avg_CPI, 
                ROUND(AVG(Temperature),2) AS avg_temp
FROM PortfolioProjects..features
GROUP BY Store
ORDER BY Store

Store   avg_unempl avg_CPI avg_temp
1   7.44    217.27  66.91
2   7.4 216.92  66.73
3   7.01    220.69  70.39
4   5.65    129.2   61.42
5   6.16    217.84  68.22
6   6.41    218.84  68.5


SELECT  tra.Store, sto.Type, sto.Size,
                ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 1 OR IsHoliday = 0
                    THEN Weekly_Sales
                    END),2) AS tot_sales,
                ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 1
                    THEN Weekly_Sales
                    END),2) AS hol_sales,
                ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 0
                    THEN Weekly_Sales
                    END),2) AS non_hol_sales
FROM PortfolioProjects..train tra, PortfolioProjects..stores sto
WHERE  tra.Store = sto.Store
GROUP BY tra.Store, sto.Size, sto.Type

Store   Type    Size    tot_sales   hol_sales   non_hol_sales
1   A   151315  222402808.85    16657476.56 205745332.29
2   A   202307  275382440.98    20792669    254589771.98
3   B   37392   57586735.07 4378110.5   53208624.57
4   A   205863  299543953.38    22431026.24 277112927.14
5   B   34875   45475688.9  3595016.07  41880672.83
6   A   202505  223756130.64    16809079.27 206947051.37
```

Comment: Your edits made the formatting worse, so I've rolled them back. Do not paste images of code or data, only paste as text

Comment: Consider using the standard, modern explicit join not outdated [implicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/1422451) as you do in second query.

Comment: "combine them together into one table" doesn't mean anything in particular. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Code that does not do what one wishes it did does not communicate the doing of what one wishes it did.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the grouped results of the first query, and then add those columns to the `GROUP BY`. You could alternatively group up both queries first and join themm afterwards, as both are essentially grouped only by unique `Store`.

```sql
SELECT
  sto.Store,
  sto.Type,
  sto.Size,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 1 OR IsHoliday = 0
            THEN Weekly_Sales
            END), 2) AS tot_sales,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 1
            THEN Weekly_Sales
            END), 2) AS hol_sales,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN IsHoliday = 0
            THEN Weekly_Sales
            END), 2) AS non_hol_sales,
  f.avg_unempl,
  f.avg_CPI,
  f.avg_temp
FROM train tra
JOIN stores sto ON tra.Store = sto.Store
JOIN (
    SELECT
      f.Store,
      ROUND(AVG(f.Unemployment), 2) AS avg_unempl, 
      ROUND(AVG(f.CPI), 2) AS avg_CPI, 
      ROUND(AVG(f.Temperature), 2) AS avg_temp
    FROM features f
    GROUP BY f.Store
) f ON f.Store = sto.Store
GROUP BY
  sto.Store,
  sto.Size,
  sto.Type,
  f.avg_unempl,
  f.avg_CPI,
  f.avg_temp;
```

Comment: It worked , thank you for helping out with this.